# Disabling the preloader after the data appears on the website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How can I set the preloader in `axios.interceptor` to turn off how will the data be displayed on the page? At this point, I can see the data is downloaded, the preloader turn off and I can see the jump as the data appears on the page. Intended effect: disabling the preloader when data appears on the website.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ca6osn?file=src%2FApp.js

```
Axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {

  // spinning start to show
  // UPDATE: Add this code to show global loading indicator
  document.body.classList.add('loading-indicator');

  return config
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

Axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {

  // spinning hide
  // UPDATE: Add this code to hide global loading indicator
  document.body.classList.remove('loading-indicator');

  return response;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
        title: []
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProfile();
    }, []);


    const loadProfile = () => { 

        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`,
          })
          .then(res => {

        setValues({...values, title: res.data});
          })
          .catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err.response.data);
      
          })
  }

  return (
    
    <div>
       {values.title.map(data => (
          <div style={{ border: "1px black solid" }}>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
          </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

*CSS*

```
.loading-indicator:before {
    content: '';
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.loading-indicator:after {
    content: 'Loading';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1001;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.5rem;        
}
```

Comment: You mean to disable the loading thing after initial fetch so that it doesn't show up for following requests?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand the problem. Can you clarify what you mean by _"disabling the preloader"_?

Comment: test it => https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kwy98r

Comment: @RameshReddy  my problem. for example: I am downloading an avatar. the preloader starts. preloader deleted. avatar appears on the site after disabling the preloader. It doesn't look nice. it should be like this - the avatar will be loaded on the site, then the preloader will disappear

Comment: @Yousaf my problem. for example: I am downloading an avatar. the preloader starts. preloader deleted. avatar appears on the site after disabling the preloader. It doesn't look nice. it should be like this - the avatar will be loaded on the site, then the preloader will disappear

Comment: Something [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zjexvd?file=src/App.js)?

Comment: It seams working fine with your set up, i have tried to display an image but everything is ok --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lwhut9?file=src%2FApp.js.

However i am displaying the image as a data url, I suppose it an url in your case that can explain the delay.

In that case what you can do is to download the image too like i am doing or setting a loader on the image block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it using the `Axios.interceptors` because there will always be a lag between the time the data received to the time the data gets render. However, I can suggest you check in the code if the data exists already and decide what to do depends on this. You can change the className of the outer div depending on your data.

It should be something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
        title: []
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProfile();
    }, []);


    const loadProfile = () => { 

        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`,
          })
          .then(res => {

        setValues({...values, title: res.data});
          })
          .catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err.response.data);
      
          })
  }

  return (
    
    <div className={values?.title?.length ? null : "loading-indicator"}>
       {values.title.map(data => (
          <div style={{ border: "1px black solid" }}>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
          </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you are not sure if data will be received from the server you can also create a new boolean variable in the state which will change from false to true when you get a response from the Axios request and use it to change the className of the div.